# Save method not working in laravel controller with no error message

Tags: php, laravel

I'm in a situation that i still couldn't figure out how to solve.
I have a function in a Laravel controller that ends in save, everything goes nice and i got no errors but the data don't go to the DB.

I already made a lot of tests and everything is as expected but don't persist the data.

Can someone help me?

I've looked in a lot of places and didn't find anything that could help me, find some things about the id typo but is not my case.

Here's the function in the controller:

```
public function saveCodeList(Request $request)
{
    try{
        \DB::beginTransaction();
        $input = $request->all();

        foreach ($input as $i){
            $pecaId = $this->TecmanutencaoPecaM
                ->where('peca', $i['peca'])
                ->select('id')
                ->first();

            if($pecaId){
                $codPeca = new TecManutencaoEstoqueCodPeca();
                $codPeca->idPeca = $pecaId->id;
                $codPeca->codigo = $i['codigo'];
                $codPeca->emEstoque = 's';

                if ($codPeca->save()) {
                    return response()->json('salvo', 200);
                } else {
                    return response()->json('Erro ao salvar');
                }
            }  elseif ($i['codigo'] !== null || $i !== '') {
                return response()->json('Sem códigos a adicionar', 200);
            }
        }

        \DB::commit();
    } catch (\Exception $e){
        \DB::rollback();
        return response()->json($e.'erro');
    }
}
```

I'm using Vue in the frontend.

Any help will be most appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are committing the database after you have a returned a response, as a result you are never actually committing the transaction to the database. You could solve this by making sure you commit the transaction before returning the `json` response.

For example:

```php
if ($codPeca->save()) {
    \DB::commit();
    return response()->json('salvo', 200);
} else {
    ...
```

Comment: thank you very much, that really solve my problem, i thought that the way it was would work in the same way...
Thanks a lot one more time.